# C# How to use OrderBy with a property on a nested class?

Tags: c#

I have a IEnumerable collection of a class which I want to sort.
One of the properties I want to sort is in a nested class.
What is the syntax to make this work?
The code below shows what I am trying to do, although it does not work.

```
    AbsenceViewModel avm = new AbsenceViewModel();
    if (sort.Column != null)
    {
        if (sort.Column == "OtherLeaveName")
            avm.ListNames = avm.ListNames .OrderBy("NestedClass.Name", sort.Direction);
        else
            avm.ListNames = avm.ListNames (sort.Column, sort.Direction);
    }
```

So putting in "NestedClass.Name" doesn't work. What do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 4):

```
avm.ListNames.OrderBy(x => x.NestedClass.Name)
```

Comment: Also if you want to Order by another property after that use avm.ListNames.OrderBy(x => x.NestedClass.Name).ThenBy(y=> y.NestedClass.Whatever) You can check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756.aspx#OrderBySimple1 for more info.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. "cannot convert lambda expression type to 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: And I have put in using System.Linq

Comment: Of what type is avm.ListNames? Post your AbsenceViewModel code!

Comment: any idea how one might do this with a string property? we were able to make one but only one level. 

ex at one level: `avm.ListNames.OrderBy("Age")` at 2 levels: `avm.ListNames.OrderBy("Profile.Age")`. we don't have a working code for 2 or n levels.